# Jms not working after update to spring boot 3 (and ConnectionFactory from javax to jakarta)

Tags: java, spring-boot, jms

After update from SpringBoot v.2.5.5 to v3.1.0 it was necessary to update also `ConnectionFactory` from `javax.jms.ConnectionFactory` to `jakarta.jms.ConnectionFactory`.
I haven't changed anything else. Unfortunately now I'm getting an errors like this:
`ERROR - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'tServerEvent' - retrying using FixedBackOff{interval=5000, currentAttempts=0, maxAttempts=unlimited}. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://localhost:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information`

I investigated it and compared with the old `javax.ConnectionFactory` and it seems that default `brokerUrl` for them is different

for `javax.jms.ConnectionFactory` it was  : `vm://localhost?broker.persistent=false`
for `jakarta.jms.ConnectionFactory` it is : `tcp://localhost:61616`

Even if I manually set broker url, like this:

```
spring:
  activemq:
    broker-url: vm://localhost?broker.persistent=false
```

it is not working still and the error is:  `Cause: Could not create Transport. Reason: java.io.IOException: Transport scheme NOT recognized: [vm]`

I don't know why the default brokerUrl is different for jakarta.ConnectionFactory and old javax.ConnectionFactory and don't know how can I run my application succesfullt.
I would appreciate if you have some tips for me.

And here is code with `JmsListenerContainerFacroty` Bean with ConnectionFactory:

```
import jakarta.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jms.DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jms.annotation.EnableJms;
import org.springframework.jms.config.DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.jms.config.JmsListenerContainerFactory;

@Configuration
@EnableJms
public class JmsConfig {

    @Bean
    public JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> myFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
        return factory;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 8):

Support for ActiveMQ was [removed in Spring Boot 3.0](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Migration-Guide#other-removals) as is did not support JMS 3.0 (the `jakarta.jms.*` APIs). Spring Boot 3.1 [restored support for auto-configuring an ActiveMQ client](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.1-Release-Notes#activemq-support). Embedded broker support has not been restored as ActiveMQ's broker does not yet support JMS 3.0.

To use ActiveMQ will Spring Boot 3.1, you will have to use an external broker as [Spring Boot's ActiveMQ smoke test does](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/6176eaa0189ee71638693079eb35fcd9dbb0d01f/spring-boot-tests/spring-boot-smoke-tests/spring-boot-smoke-test-activemq).