# Spring boot 3.2.0 Unit testing with JMS because unable to connect any Embedded ActiveMQ Broker how can I do this?

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, jms, activemq-classic

I want to create connection with EmbeddedActiveMQBroker and also want to set String property in Message so that listener can extract those String properties from Message. I want to use Message.class to send and receive message.

My goal is to produce message in this message set String property and produce message to input queue .Next part is my listener should able to listen from this input queue and able to extract those String properties from Message.

```
import org.apache.activemq.junit.EmbeddedActiveMQBroker;
import org.junit.ClassRule;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class JmsMessageListeningAndSendingTest extends IntegrationTestBase {
  @ClassRule
  public static EmbeddedActiveMQBroker embeddedBroker = new EmbeddedActiveMQBroker();
}
```

```
Application.yml

  activemq:
    broker-url: tcp://localhost:61616
    close-timeout: 15
    packages:
      trusted: com.broker.activemq.entities,java.lang
    password: admin
    user: admin
    in-memory: true
    pool:
      enabled: false
```

```
build.gradle
testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.9.1'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.9.1'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:4.8.1'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-contract-stub-runner:4.1.0'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:5.8.0'
    testImplementation 'org.testcontainers:testcontainers:1.19.3'
    runtimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'

    implementation 'org.apache.activemq:activemq-broker:6.0.1'
    implementation 'org.apache.activemq:activemq-all:6.0.1'
    testImplementation 'org.apache.activemq.tooling:activemq-junit:6.0.1'
    testImplementation 'org.testcontainers:junit-jupiter:1.16.3'
```

```
Error Description:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/jms/JMSException
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:862)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:681)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:639)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:525)
    at org.apache.activemq.junit.EmbeddedActiveMQBroker.<init>(EmbeddedActiveMQBroker.java:69)
```

Comment: Could you share the pom.xml for config ? My guess is that you have dependency mismatch

Comment: this is based on Gradle

Comment: Could you then share the gradle equivalent of the pom.xml in maven to see the dependencies ? Thanks

Comment: Is Embedded active MQ broker compatible with Spring Boot version 3.2.0 ?

Comment: ActiveMQ just migrated to jakarta in series 6. That's why I'm asking

Comment: When I was trying to create connection factory for Embedded active MQ broker with Jakarta JMS connection it was showing me error with ActiveMQConnectionFactory because ActiveMQConnectionFactory needs connection factory from JavaX JMS but my Spring Boot version is 3.2.0 which is by default taking Jakarta JMS

Answer (score 0):

As pointed in the comments, it must be a dependency problem with SB3 (jakarta) and ActiveMQ embedded version.

Starting from v6, ActiveMQ is now jakarta compatible.

You should be using 6.0.1 of the following and try to see if it fixes your problem.
Maven :

```xml
<groupId>org.apache.activemq.tooling</groupId>
<artifactId>activemq-junit</artifactId>
<version>6.0.1</version>
```

Or gradle :

```
org.apache.activemq.tooling:activemq-junit:6.0.1
```

If not fixed by itself with this dependency, you can still follow that [guide](https://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-embed-a-broker-inside-a-connection) to create EmbeddedServer from java.

**Edit**

After seeing the gradle file, the faulty section is

```
implementation 'org.apache.activemq:activemq-all:5.4.2'
```

It'll mix up ActiveMQ 6 with 5 dependencies.
You should upgrade this to 6.0.1 too

Comment: Already added this check my build.gradle above mentioned

Comment: Seen your gradle file, thanks for sharing. Pointed out one issue in it, edited answer

Comment: I couldn't able to connect to EmbeddedActiveMQBroker. Now the Error is initializationError

Comment: The exception says : `log4j-slf4j2-impl cannot be present with log4j-to-slf4j`. It seems you have both artifacts

Comment: You should spot which dependency is coming with the artifact (I guess the wanted one is slf4j2) and exclude the non wanted one (log4j-to-slf4j)

Comment: after removal of org.apache.logging.slf4j.SLF4JServiceProvider@baf1bb3 it's showing class not found exception

Comment: This SLF4J error is arriving from  org.apache.activemq.tooling:activemq-junit:6.0.1 after removal of above dependency error has gone and new exception arised and I mentioned above

Comment: Could you share the new exception ?

Comment: above I have shared

Comment: This is strange. I think you still have dependencies issues since I see no javax import in `EmbeddedActiveMQBroker`. Please check if one of your dependency is still not tied to activemq 5

Comment: I have only written this public static EmbeddedActiveMQBroker embeddedBroker = new EmbeddedActiveMQBroker(); when tried with Connection factory that takes Javax Jms connection factory returns new ActiveMQConnectionFactory but when tried with Jakarta Jms connection factory with ActiveMQConnectionFactory it shows error

Comment: The easier way for me to help you would be to share github link with what's working in a branch and what doesn't in another. I get confused with your last comment. BTW : you should align the `org.testcontainers` artifacts version

Comment: My goal is to connect with EmbeddedActiveMQBroker in Spring boot 3.2.0. how it is possible please tell me

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76380103/jms-not-working-after-update-to-spring-boot-3-and-connectionfactory-from-javax

Comment: Someone has told that about broker in above link